# Push firebase values to array

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have two databases that i want to consult and store the results of both in an unique array. Problem is: for some reason, the same values are being pushed to the array over and over again, instead of each value.

```
chats = [];
chat = {};

    firebase.database().ref("users").child(this.AngularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).child("chats").on("child_added", (data) => {
      this.chat = {};
      this.chat['topic'] = data.val().topic;
      console.log("1");
      firebase.database().ref("users").child(data.val().otherUserUid).once("value", (data) => {
        this.chat['otherUsersName'] = data.val().name;
        this.chat['otherUsersPhoto'] = data.val().photo;
        console.log("1");
      }).then(()=>{
        this.chats.push(this.chat);
        console.log("3");
    });
  });
```

What i want the this.chats array to be:

```
[
  {topic: "Tech", otherUsersName: "Jonh Turner", otherUsersPhoto: "jonh_profile.png"},
  {topic: "Food", otherUsersName: "Paul Kant", otherUsersPhoto: "paul_profile.png"},
  {topic: "Science", otherUsersName: "Jimmy Poer", otherUsersPhoto: "jimmy_profile.png"}
]
```

What i get:

```
[
    {topic: "Tech", otherUsersName: "Jonh Turner", otherUsersPhoto: "jonh_profile.png"},
    {topic: "Tech", otherUsersName: "Jonh Turner", otherUsersPhoto: "jonh_profile.png"},
    {topic: "Tech", otherUsersName: "Jonh Turner", otherUsersPhoto: "jonh_profile.png"}
]
```

How i want the console to be:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

What i get:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Comment: The first line inside your `child_added` callback: `this.chat = {};` - what is the goal of clearing that variable every time a new DB value is added at that path?

Comment: so that only the current child is added to the array. If i dont clear it, all the past children will also be pushed, which will result in a lot of duplicated children

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want

```
firebase.database()
.ref("users")
.child(this.AngularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
.child("chats")
.on("child_added", (data) => {
    firebase.database()
    .ref("users")
    .child(data.val().otherUserUid)
    .once("value", (dataother) => {
        this.chats.push({
            topic: data.val().topic,
            otherUsersName: dataother.val().name,
            otherUsersPhoto: data.val().photo
        });
    });
});
```

Note the `dataother` in the inner call